# Swiftmailer Spam Test

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I've decided on what I'm going to use ([Postmarkapp](http://spamcheck.postmarkapp.com/doc)) to check the spam value of my e-mails before sending them out. However, to get a true answer from Postmarkapp, I need to send the full e-mail with headers. I am using swiftmailer.

How can I get the full header message using swiftmailer BEFORE it actually gets sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
mailer->send();
```

You just go:

```
mailer->toString();
```

Keep in mind, this does not have ALL headers, because I think more is added by the receiving server before being passed along. Which means, you really do have the raw version of it, but it won't help that much with identifying server factors that could influence your spam score, as it most definitely does affect your spam score. However, it's still a decent indicator for a quick copy spot check...